# Modify wiki page (Confluence) programmatically

Tags: python, html, urllib2

I'd like to modify a wiki page (Confluence by Atlassian - JIRA editors) programmatically (in python). What I tried so far is to simulate user behaviour:

1. click on Edit button
2. change content of a `textarea` input
3. submit changes with Save button

Part 1 is ok since I have the URL corresponding to an edit of the page, part 2 (retrieval of the page and modification) is ok too, but I don't know how to achieve step 3... I'm using `urllib2`.

Thanks for your help !!

**EDIT**: XML-RPC is indeed the solution, [this example](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DISC/XML-RPC+Page+Updater+Example) does exactly what I want !

Comment: Can you please post the solution as the answer?  I cannot view that page in the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like the absolutely wrong way to go about it.

First off, Confluence has a plugin architecture which should allow you to [manage content](http://wiki.customware.net/repository/display/ATLASSIAN/API+-+Confluence+-+Creating+and+Modifying+Pages) programmatically from the application itself without any kind of HTTP requests. Secondly, even if you don't want to, or can't, use the plugin API for some reason, the next obvious option is to use the [SOAP/XML-RPC API](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Confluence+XML-RPC+and+SOAP+APIs).

There is no reason to actually mess with `button`s and `textarea`s unless you're trying to do some kind of end-to-end test that includes testing GUI (e.g. automated cross-browser testing).

Comment: Wonderful ! I won't use the 1st solution because I'm using Python, but the 2nd one is just awesome (just found a sample that does exactly what I want) !!!

Answer (score 9):

```
# write to a confluence page
import xmlrpclib

CONFLUENCE_URL = "https://intranet.example.com/confluence/rpc/xmlrpc" 
CONFLUENCE_LOGIN = "a confluence username here"
CONFLUENCE_PASSWORD = "confluence pwd for username"

# get this from the page url while editing
# e.g. ../editpage.action?pageId=132350005 <-- here
PAGE_ID = "132350005" 
client = xmlrpclib.Server(CONFLUENCE_URL, verbose = 0)
auth_token = client.confluence2.login(CONFLUENCE_LOGIN, CONFLUENCE_PASSWORD)
page = client.confluence2.getPage(auth_token, PAGE_ID)

# and write the new contents
page['content'] = "!!!your content here!!!"

result = client.confluence2.storePage(auth_token, page)
client.confluence2.logout(auth_token)
```

Note that confluence modifies your html code when you do this.  It strips out scripts, styles and sometimes title attributes on elements for example.  In order to get that stuff back in you then need to use their macro code.

Easiest way to do this is to edit the page in confluence and make it look like you want and then grab the page and do a print page['content'] to see what magical new stuff the atlassian people have decided to do to standard html.

Comment: I believe you would need to add `client.confluence2.storePage(auth_token, page)` before the logout for this to work, wouldn't you?

Comment: That code is modified from a working script.  I suspect the index assignment is doing the work.  I'll double check when I get in to work tomorrow though.

Comment: @Jerry you are quite right.  I must have missed that line somehow.   I have fixed the script accordingly.  thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @dementedhedgehog I cannot get the `auth_token = cliient.confluence2.login(CONFLUENCE_LOGIN, CONFLUENCE_PASSWORD)` line to work.  Getting a `405 Method Not Allowed` protocol error.  Do I need to install something or enable permissions on Confluence or something?

Comment: Also confused on the URL I use.  Let's say the page I want to edit is `http://my.server.net:port/confluence/blah/myname/mypage`.  Do I copy this whole thing as the `CONFLUENCE_URL`?

Comment: Nvm, figured it out.  Needed to be `http://my.server.net:port/confluence/` then ignore everything after that and add `rpc/.xmlprc`.  Also no need for additional permissions.

Comment: @MrPickles (for future readers as you've worked it out).  The url is the link to the xmlrpc definition for confluence, as you've pointed out that might be a little different based on installation (and might change with future versions of confluence).  The PAGE_ID is what identifies the page you want to edit in the confluence page database.  You can find that by manually going to the page and editing it, then the ID will be in the url for that page.  You can create new pages as well using this api should you wish to do so.

Comment: @dementedhedgehog The above works perfectly for removing the previous content and adding new content...but how do you just modify content?  For example, if I have a large group of tables...how do I just update one column from a specific table?

Comment: Get the page text from the page dictionary and then modify it, thus:  text = page['content'];
text += " some extra text for the page .. ";
page['content'] = text